# Mini panels content not showing

Tags: panels

I am making a builder mini panel with two rows and three regions in each. Each region display a node.
     The problem is that only the first node is showing, rest just refuse to show.
     I have tried setting the styles of each region from default to no style, but the problem still persists. Here is a screen shot of my page [image]

Comment: Just going to do it with floated divs inside of div with max-width